# Replacing flag on astronaut

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How to replace flag (U.S flag in the picture below) with other flag (for example, United Kingdom) on astronaut using Photoshop CS6?

Displacement mapping gave weird results, and blending did not work out nicely at all.

So, can anyone point at some direction, how to do that?

Thanks
[image: Astronaut]

Comment: Have you tried using the warp tool and then using adjustment layers to darken?

Comment: Does the UK have astronauts?

Comment: @AndrewH Yes, however that belt gets on the way. I guess using lasso tool and dividing flag to 2 at the belt might give the desired result.

Comment: @Scott - No idea. Just for example. The point is to achieve same thing as this- http://wild.as/pages/hell/cover-astronaut.png There is Austria flag on that astronaut. The original image is the one posted with U.S flag. How they did that magic is why I am here.

Comment: I was just kind of curious Astro, that's all :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the warp tool for this.

1) Find flag

2) Rotate flag and scale down

3) Bring up the transform options (edit - transform or ctrl + T) and select warp.

4) I first lowered the opacity of the flag layer to see easily transform the edges. Bring the edges of the flag to cover up the American flag :(

[image: warp flag]

5) I then traced the arm thing with the pen tool and added a layer mask to the flag to show the arm thing. You fill the selection with black.

6) I then added a solid black color to clip the flag and then used a clipping mask to not show some of the black

Result

[image: result of astro]

Comment: Wow, good job! The masking works. Amazing. Thank you!